# How should I organize my update/draw logic when using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, animation, rendering, conventions, requestanimationframe

The JavaScript code for my HTML5 game has the following structure:

```
// <body onload="load()">
function load() {} // Load all images then call init()
function init() {} // Get all images ready for the game logic then call animate()
function animate() {} // Use requestAnimationFrame(), update() and drawing()
function update() {} // Update the game logic
function drawing() {} // Render the images on canvas
```

The issue lies inside `animate()`. I'm not finding any consistent sources around the web on how to organize `requestAnimationFrame()`, `update()` and `drawing()` in it.

I tried to elaborate it by myself, but the game **did** run in pratically any approach, like passing either `animate()`, `update()` or `drawing()` as an argument to `requestAnimationFrame()`, or having `requestAnimationFrame()` at either the beginning or the end of the function, or having any of these functions in any order, or one function inside another, etc.

That, however, doesn't mean anything is fine. Some of those arrangements result in issues that I'd find out only later, like when testing in a different computer or at a different frame rate. And then I have to go back to the code to try another approach.

So, how should I organize that? I'd appreciate if you can present me a proper algorithm, and even more if you have any good sources on teaching about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's up to opinions what's best. Some will prefer to have a completely separated time loop for the logic update and use rAF only for the drawings, some will prefer to have everything in the same place etc. As long as your code correctly expects rAF to not fire at regular intervals, you should be fine with whatever structure. The only small note: while I do some protos in online IDEs, I always put the rAF call last because there, the "fake" consoles are expensive and having an error thrown in a loop is painful. But other than that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `requestAnimationFrame` to call `animate` repeatedly. `animate` calls `update` then `draw`. That's basically it. To have more control of time since you don't control the intervals *exactly*, it makes sense to pass the last time that `animate` was invoked. Maybe event the delta time that has passed since, makes more sense. Then you can use delta time to calculate distance given a speed and so on.

Here's an example of a game loop which is explained [here](https://codeincomplete.com/articles/javascript-game-foundations-the-game-loop/):

```
var now,
    dt   = 0,
    last = timestamp(),
    step = 1/60;

function frame() {
  now = timestamp();
  dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now - last) / 1000);
  while(dt > step) {
    dt = dt - step;
    update(step);
  }
  render(dt);
  last = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

There are many resources online. Here's a decent one for beginners https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/

Comment: "official" as in ...? Who's to make "official" code? That's pretty much against the ideas promoted by anything that could be seen as "official working groups" on the web. And why would you execute the `update()` step several times if you do pass the delta time to it? Just pass the real delta time instead of passing this hardcoded `step` and make your inner logic embrace the delta time directly.

Comment: You are right I fixed the wording and added the source. That `update` is a trick to allow for "filling the gaps" using linear interpolation by carrying over the reminder. I didn't test it though.

Comment: The function passed to `requestAnimationFrame` recieves a time argument, which should be used to calculate delta time. This takes care of different refresh rates.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame